# Create a variable having name stored in a string variable

Tags: java, string, class, instance, instance-variables

Let's say:

I have a Class Animal and I want to create an instance of that class by the name `"bird"`.
`"bird"` is stored in a `String`.

How to do that?

```
String variable_name = "bird";
```

I want to use the string in variable_name as an Animal's instance.

```
Animal bird = new Animal();
```

Thanks...

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking. Do you want to have a field inside ``Animal`` that when accessed would return ``"bird"``, or do you want to have the actual instance name of the ``Animal`` be based on some value in a ``String``, in this case ``bird``?

Comment: I want to use the string stored in variable_name as a new variable of type Animal

Comment: do you want to instantiate a new `Animal` and assign it to the field with name 'variable_name' ?

Comment: assign it to the field with name 'variable_name'

Comment: why do you want to use the string to determine the variable name? the name of a local variable doesn't affect code outside of the block where it is declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the reflection

```
public class DynamicSetTest {

    private Animal animal1 = null;
    private Animal animal2 = null;
    private Animal animal3 = null;

    public Animal getAnimal1() {
        return animal1;
    }
    public Animal getAnimal2() {
        return animal2;
    }
    public Animal getAnimal3() {
        return animal3;
    }

    public void setField(String name, Animal value) throws Exception {
            Field field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
            field.set(this, value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DynamicSetTest t = new DynamicSetTest();
        Animal anAnimal = new Animal();
        t.setField("animal3", anAnimal);
        assert t.getAnimal3() == anAnimal;
    }
}
```

Note that you have a field for each possible name. You also have to handle the case if the variable doesn't exist.

I'm wondering if you instead want to use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and add objects using that name like

```
Map<String, Animal> animals = new HashMap<String, Animal>();
animals.put("animal3", anAnimal);
assert animals.get("animal3") == anAnimal;
```

Comment: In general, reflection isn't worth the trouble.

Comment: I agree, that's why I suggested a map to store objects by name.

Comment: Actually that's a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Add `name` as a field in `Animal` and ask for it in the constructor.

```
class Animal {

    String name;

    public Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then when you construct an animal use:

```
Animal bird = new Animal("bird");
Animal deer = new Animal("deer");
Animal wumpus = new Animal("wumpus");
```

Comment: e.g: Animal deer = new Animal("deer");

In your example, you've written Animal deer. but I want to use the string stored in variable_name as a new variable of type Animal

Something like:

String variable_name = "deer";
Animal variable_name= new Animal();